# align div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am creating an online shopping site for my project, in product list I used `float:left` for listing them properly but the problem is the size of product div will be variable, if size of one div increases it ruins my listing design. please help me
this is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="unit"  style="height:140px">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="unit">
            </div>          
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.unit{float:left;width:170px;height:133px;border: 1px solid red;margin:5px;}
```

this is fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/VPESu/

thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I assumed correctly, use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

Comment: its working just remove inline height from div...

Comment: @DipeshParmar The inline height is just for testing, I think. (to let us know what would happen if height or width of a div is increased of decreased)

Comment: @Mr_Green is right, if height is increased  lower list should be shifted according to largest element, width will remain same everytime

Comment: @Mr_Green the way you told me is working fine but the problem is div is shifting upwards I want it to shift down...I've updated the fiddle give it a shot...

Comment: So you mean if a element has more height than other elements then it should shift down. right?

Comment: @BharatSoni Then you need to look at javascript or jQuery. First of all keep your elements in an array. and then sort those elements based on height. Then append it to the parent element. Automatically, the more height div will come down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `float` and add `display:inline-block`

```
.unit{
    width:170px;
    height:133px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:5px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:top
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VPESu/3/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use the **max-height** property (and **max-width** if required):

```
.unit{float:left;width:170px;height:133px;max-height:133px;border: 1px solid red;margin:5px;}
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want to set Fixed-Height/Width, you can try this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

**Edit:** Equal Height Divs (to the highest div):

http://filamentgroup.com/examples/equalHeights/

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

Comment: This will fix the height of the div forever (not let it increase dynamically as OP stated in post).

Comment: i assumed since he already have a 'height' property he wants it to be all the same height.

Comment: Yup, not clear from OP's explanation. whether he/she wants to vary the width and height or not. Till OP's response can't say anything.

Comment: there is this link, i will add it to the post for 'pinterest' like divs.
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @muhammad omar all I want is to shift lower part to height of largest element

Comment: @BharatSoni, Something like that: http://filamentgroup.com/examples/equalHeights/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing float:left to display:inline-block will work but will look quite ugly if some of the heights are dramatically different from the other ones.

If they will only vary in height be a few pixels then I'd go for that solution.

Otherwise you could consider a couple of javascript based solutions.

The Equal Heights plug-in will make all the divs have the same height:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

OR

The Masonry plug-in will cause the DIVS to display like the grid layout on Pinterest:

http://masonry.desandro.com/